# Bash mysql query: ERROR 1054 (42S22) 'file name' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, bash

I have found many similar problems with an unknown column name, but none that report the same as this and I'm lost:

ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'tad.sh' in 'field list'

'tad.sh' is the name of the bash script itself.

The code:

```
#!/bin/sh
FPATH="/home/bermans/CHIT/"
DATE="$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"
FNAME="transfer-authority.csv"
HEADS="\"Time\", \"Urgent\", \"Initials\", \"Transfer from\", \"From description\",    \"Transfer to\", \"To description\", \"Sum\", \"In respect of\""

params="-u #### -p#### chit"
s1="SELECT "
s2=" UNION"
s3=" SELECT *"
s4=" FROM \`transfer-authority\`"
s5=" WHERE Time > DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 24 HOUR )"
s6=" INTO OUTFILE "
s7=" FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"'"
s8=" LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
selectend=";"

echo $s1$HEADS$s2$s3$s4$s5$s6\'$FPATH$DATE$FNAME$\'$s7$s8$selectend | mysql $params
```

I want a CSV file to be made with headers every day of the entries made for the last 24 hours. I'm going to run this as a cronjob and then email and delete the file.

Any help is grealty appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `| mysql $params` part of the echo statement and you'll have a nasty surprise ;-)

The problem is that `s3=" SELECT *"` gets injected into an `echo` statement and `*` gets interpreted by shell as wildcard. It's the same as if you type this into a console:

```
echo *
```

Try double quoting the `echo` arguments (you'll no longer need to escape single quotes):

```
echo "$s1$HEADS$s2$s3$s4$s5$s6'$FPATH$DATE$FNAME$'$s7$s8$selectend"
```

Comment: I really should have noticed that! Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
mysql -u #### -p#### -e $s1$HEADS$s2$s3$s4$s5$s6\'$FPATH$DATE$FNAME$\'$s7$s8$ chit
```